# How to increment a C program's memory (RAM) using successive malloc function calls

Tags: c, linux, malloc, ram

I'm writing a C test program that calls the malloc function successively every one second, the purpose is to test the RAM limit of an ARM-based processor running in linux system,

I wrote the code below and i tested it before in my computer (OS: ubuntu 16.04) but the RAM occupation (VmRSS) does not change every second, but every 10 seconds I guess, could anyone explain why ?

```
FILE *trace;
int compteur=0;
char *var;
while (1)
{
    trace=fopen("trace.txt","a");
    compteur++;
    var=(char *)malloc(100000);
    fprintf(trace,"%d\n",compteur);
    fclose(trace);
    sleep(1);
}
```

I launch this command to check the program's RAM occupation

```
 cat /proc/prog_pid/status | grep "VmRSS"
```

Expected results: RAM incremeting 100K each one second

Real results: RAM incrementing 1M each 10+ seconds

Comment: The implementation of `malloc` may get memory from the system by large chunks.

Comment: The OS doesn't have to give it the exact amount of memory every time. That would have huge overhead for a program that does a lot of little allocations. Instead, it can just give the program a big chunk of memory and then it doesn't have to give more until that runs out.

Comment: every time a process malloc(), it will get a page allocated to it by memory management unit, page size depends on your system configuration. Untill the memory is present in this page it will not increase the size. once it need more than this allocated space again it get a new page. so you are seeing this behavior.

Comment: you can refer to for paging and dynamic allocation: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_3.html

Comment: There are more sensible ways to get the memory limit than attempt to exhaust it. `/proc/meminfo` for example.

Comment: Thank you all for these information

Comment: @eerorika, /proc/meminfo/ does not show the real limit of RAM usage, because the free memory and cached memory change their values

Answer (score 0):

From some comments, I found out that the implementation of malloc may get memory from the system by large chunks and the OS doesn't have to give it the exact amount of memory every time , by writing in a txt file, the number of allocated bytes,i was able to determine exactly the ram limit.